# How can I change the objectId from a class on http://parse.com?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I'm calling the RestAPI methods to update an object https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating and I'm getting a success response, but the objetId won't change.

Answer (score 2):

The objectId is a non-editable field so you won't be able to update it.  If you need to use your own ID, you will have to add a separate field in addition to the objectId field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can change objectId. It's a unique identifier assigned by the system at instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless you import a class. You cannot import a class if a class by the same name already exists so you will need to merge that data first.